# addText() change the text color inside a QGraphicsView

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt4, qgraphicsview

I have managed to make a vertical text label inside a QGraphicsView which is imported from showGui.UI. Everything is exactly how I want it except I can't figure out to change the text color. setStyleSheet doesn't work with QGraphicsViews.  I made another attempt with QPainter but i couldn't get that to roate correctly or inside of my graphics view. All the documentation I have found is in C++ and that leaves me bewildered. I think adding:

```
  self.trans_graphicsView_cat.drawForeground(QPainter(setPen(QtGui.QColor(168, 34, 3)))
```

into the createScene Function will do it but I haven't been able to crack it.

My Code:

```
class MainDialog(QtGui.QMainWindow, showGui.Ui_MainWindow):
    dbPath = appDataPath + "barter.db"
    dbConn = sqlite3.connect(dbPath)
    dbConn.text_factory = str



def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(MainDialog, self).__init__(parent)
    self.setupUi(self)

    self.text = self.tr("Categories")
    self.createScene()

def createScene(self):
    scene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene()
    self.trans_graphicsView_cat.setScene(scene)
    item = scene.addText(self.text, QtGui.QFont('Arial Black', 15, QtGui.QFont.Light))
    item.rotate(270)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [addText](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsscene.html#addText) method returns a [QGraphicsTextItem](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicstextitem.html). This class has a [setDefaultTextColor](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicstextitem.html#setDefaultTextColor) method which should allow you to change the colour of the text.

Alternatively, you could create your own instance of `QGraphicsTextItem` and then use [addItem](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsscene.html#addItem) to add it to the scene. Note that the `QGraphicsTextItem` class has a [setHtml](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicstextitem.html#setHtml) method which should give you even greater control over the formatting of the text.

Comment: Thank you, the first suggestion did the trick! I would like to better understand the second alternative, but I think I would have to see the code example written in python. You already did enough though! Thanks again and i posted the working code below.